# How can I monitor the input signal with effects applied in Adobe Audition?

Tags: macos, audio-recording, adobe-audition

Can I monitor the input signal in Adobe Audition (CC Version 2015) with effects applied? I can only seem to post process the track i.e once recorded, the effects e.g. EQ seem to have been applied.

I've attached a screenshot below of how I have things set up. I'm using OSX 10.11.3 and a Focusrite Saffire Pro 24.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Session view (unselected tab in the right of the image) there is an 'i' icon next to the arm-to-record button. This seemed to get me what I needed, possibly in combination with setting the monitored channels to DAW in the Focusrite mixing panel.